# Highcharts: some x-axis labels are disappearing after using setExtremes()

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, slider, axis-labels

I was developing a solution for another question here on Stack Overflow (see [Highcharts : selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437791/highcharts-selection/38439661#38439661)) that has some simple slider elements (using `input type="range"`) to change the categories shown in a column chart. Whenever the user changes the range in either slider element, the chart is redrawn using `setExtremes()`.

I noticed that, in some instances, some of the x-axis labels disappeared, even when I moved the sliders back to their original positions. I've tinkered with a number of x-axis settings, including `minPadding`, `startOnTick`, and `tickInterval`, and none of them seem to solve "The Case of the Missing Labels."

The first screenshot below shows the chart when it's first loaded. All of the x-axis labels are present.

[image]

The second screenshot below shows the chart when I change one of the sliders. Some of the x-axis labels are now missing. It looks like they're being staggered.

[image]

Here's where the plot thickens: if I adjust the sliders to some other values, all of the labels come back:

[image]

Here's the fiddle I developed so you can see a live example of this behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/uvat8u05/

I'm curious to know why this is happening, and what settings I could use to ensure that all x-axis labels are shown, regardless of what values the user chooses in the sliders.

Thank you very much!

> **Update**: The responses from both Max Uppenkamp and Grzegorz Blachliński are valid and helpful solutions. What I also discovered by chance was that explicitly setting the slider values to integers using `parseInt()` solved this issue as well. It also helps in comparing both values to make sure a user doesn't choose an end date that is earlier than the start date.

Comment: You can use tickPositions or tickPositioner to avoid this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/uvat8u05/6/

Comment: Thank you very much, @GrzegorzBlachliński. I also happened to notice that setting my slider values to integers solved the issue as well. I amended my question to note that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be intended behavior of Highcharts, however inconsistent it may be.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061624/how-can-i-force-highcharts-to-show-every-x-axis-label-regardless-of-spacing-cons) this should be fixed in current versions of Highcharts, but you might as well try this tick formatter solution.

Edit: If the above doesn't work for you, you might be able to solve the issue by rotating your labels:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels/grid

Comment: Thank you, Max. I had tried to rotate the labels, but that didn't solve the mystery. However, the `tickPositioner` function looks very helpful.